# How to change item which located in menubar when selecting from item(3dots)

Tags: java, android

[Singlecell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKYQn.jpg) (image1)
As you see above picture the singcell text which I need to change it according to itemselected from 3 dot.

[Multicell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3izm.jpg)
When clicked the 3 dot,it will display the option for example when click multicell,I want the image1 to become multicell. How do I achieve that??

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


   MenuItem item=menu.getItem(0); // here itemIndex is int
    item.setTitle("SingleCell");




    return true;
}





@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xxml.
     id = item.getItemId();



    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.navigation_multicell) {



        selectState = 0;
      //  clearAllCells();
        boxState = 0;
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.navigation_singlecell) {




        selectState = 1;
      //  clearAllCells();
        boxState = 0;
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.navigation_box) {


        selectState = 2;

      //  clearAllCells();
        boxState = 0;
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Use custom header with text view and change text view according to selected option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom action bar for it. follow this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-custom-actionbar-in-android to create a custom action bar with elements you want

after that, you can change get a reference for that text view in the custom action bar and change text according to the user clicks